# Scrollable Lists in .bat Files

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to make a scrollable list with the arrow keys in batch files? After selecting one, can it do something like: (goto result1) etc? If it isn't possible, I just have to stick with the user inputting answers themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Batch file below use an interesting trick that consist in fill the DOSKEY history with the elements of the list. After that, a F7 key is send to the keyboard, so when a SET /P command is executed previous elements are displayed in a scrollable list (menu selection) managed by DOSKEY.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Define the options
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (First Second Third Fourth Fifth) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a Option"
)
set /A numOpts+=1
set "option[!numOpts!]=exit"

rem Clear previous doskey history
doskey /REINSTALL
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" EnterOpts
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "var="

:nextOpt
cls
echo MULTI-LINE MENU WITH OPTIONS SELECTION
echo/
rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
set /P "var=Select the desired option: "
echo/
if "%var%" equ "exit" goto :EOF
echo Option selected: "%var%"
pause
goto nextOpt


@end

var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process"),
    numOpts = parseInt(envVar("numOpts"));

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Enter menu options
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Enter a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}
```

Output example of previous program:

[image: Example of previous program]

Previous program is a Batch-JScript hybrid script; you may see [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661) for an explanation of hybrid scripts, and [this one](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661) for a further description of this program.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy if you need filenames. For other lists, it's quite difficult in pure batch.

```
echo select file with [TAB]
set /p "file=Select file name: "
echo you selected %file%
```

will toggle through all files in the directory if you press `TAB`.

You can also give the first two or three characters and then toggle through all matching files with `TAB`

It's even possible to give `*.txt` and then toggle through all `.txt` files in the current directory.

Comment: I want a list with stuff I typed and they can use the arrow keys to scroll the items on the list and pressing enter to do a special command like goto oitput1 etc.

Comment: The arrow keys are normally reserved for 'doskey'esk history browsing.

Comment: To select from a list of options is doable.  If it's more than a page full then it becomes messy.