# wshShell and WMIC working together in batch?

Tags: list, shell, batch-file, scrollable, wmic

I was trying to create a scrollable list for a batch file using the method found here: [Scrollable Lists in .bat Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965005/scrollable-lists-in-bat-files#)
Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini

One I tried adding back in my code for my regular batch a few lines at a time, I noticed that the solution doesn't work when I use WMIC. What is the reason for this and is there an easy solution? You can run the below code and then un-comment the WMIC line and see it will not work anymore.

Edit: I am using Windows 7

Thanks!

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color F0


::FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN ('WMIC csproduct GET Name /VALUE ^| FIND /I "Name="') DO SET machine=%%A


Echo Reset or Continue
Set MenuOptions=RESET Continue
call :ShowMenu

pause
exit

:ShowMenu
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (%MenuOptions%) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a"
)
rem Clear previous doskey history
doskey /REINSTALL
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" EnterOpts
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "var="

rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
set /P "MenuSelected=Option Selected: "
echo/
@end
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process"),
    numOpts = parseInt(envVar("numOpts"));

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Enter menu options
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Enter a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}
```

Comment: The only cause I see for it not to work when calling `wmic` is that maybe your batch file is called `wmic.bat` or `wmic.cmd` and it is calling itself. Also note that you are missing a `goto :eof` just before the `@end` line

Comment: I can confirm this changed behaviour i.e. no menu appears even with another executable instead of  `wmic`. Tested e.g. `findstr /N "wshShell" %~f0` (Windows 8.1).

Comment: @JosefZ,  Tested on Windows 10 64 and Windows 7 32. In both cases the posted code shows the menu, but the `doskey /reinstall` does not clean the history of previous commands, with or without `wmic`

Comment: Tested again with some executables even with `wmic` calling the batch from `cmd` prompt. `D:\bat\SO\40165693.bat` would not show a menu while `CMD /C D:\bat\SO\40165693.bat` works like a charm… @MCND I can confirm that `doskey /reinstall` does not clean the history of previous commands  (without `WMIC`) when _repeatedly_ run  `D:\bat\SO\40165693.bat` on second and after run.

Comment: I've edited the post to include that I have Windows 7. I also added the goto:eof, which seemed to help until I changed the code to: FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN ('WMIC csproduct GET Name /VALUE ^| FIND /I "Name="') DO SET machine=%%A . It doesn't work again. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SendKeys Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) sends one or more keystrokes *to the active window*. Unfortunately, `Sendkeys()` sometimes fails usually due to **focus** or **timing**, both troublesome and difficult to solve problems. I tried `pause` and `timeout`, tried `WshShell.AppActivate` in various combinations, all without success…

Finally, I found culprit in clearing previous `doskey` history via `doskey /REINSTALL` command: it installs a new copy of `doskey`. I can recommend more intuitive (and less invasive) method to clear the `doskey` command history buffer:

```
doskey /ListSize=0
doskey /ListSize=50
```

**Bonus**: FOR loops explanation.

- outer `%%A` loop to retrieve the `name` property;
- inner `%%a` loop to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

Credit: Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Working script** (Windows 8.1 64 bit):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM color F0

  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN ('
    WMIC csproduct GET Name /VALUE ^| FIND /I "Name="
  ') DO FOR %%a in ("%%~A") DO SET "_machine=%%~a"

Echo Reset or Continue %_machine%
Set "MenuOptions=%_machine% RESET Continue"  expanded merely for debugging purposes
call :ShowMenu

REM pause
exit /B

:ShowMenu
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (%MenuOptions%) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a"
)
rem Clear previous doskey history
REM this causes problems: doskey /REINSTALL
doskey /ListSize=0
doskey /ListSize=50
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" EnterOpts
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "var="

rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
set /P "MenuSelected=Option Selected: "
echo/
goto :eof
@end
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process"),
    numOpts = parseInt(envVar("numOpts"));

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Enter menu options
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Enter a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}
```